# Simplify multiple isset

Tags: php, wordpress, isset

How can i simplify the below code?

> $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fields', true );

```
if ((isset ($meta['test1'])) || (isset ($meta['test2'])) || (isset ($meta['test3'])) || (isset ($meta['test4'])) || (isset ($meta['test5'])) ){ // do this }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say simplify, do you mean *just* this `if` statement? It's certainly possible, but you'd still need a check prior to this `if` statement.

Comment: @George Simplify to check if any of these value exist, then execute function. I am trying to keep my php file size down as i have to do many checks like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean your code as a whole, then no, it doesn't get much simpler.

If, however you *just* want this `if` statement to look a little simpler, that'd be no problem, just make a check above:

```
$metaSet = isset ($meta['test1']) || isset ($meta['test2']) || isset ($meta['test3']) || isset ($meta['test4']) || isset ($meta['test5'])

if($metaSet){ /*..*/ }
```

Or you could do something a little cleverer: create an array of potential keys, map the array to an integer, 0 if it exists, 1 if it doesn't. Sum the array, and if it's more than 0, then at least one of the specified keys is set:

```
$keys = Array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'); // Update with potentials
if(atLeastOneIsSet($keys, $meta)){ /*..*/ }  

function atLeastOneIsSet($a, $m){
    $metaSet = array_sum(array_map(function($k) use ($m){
        return (int)isset($m[$k]);
    }, $a)) > 0;

    return $metaSet;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Based on your answer, i think the code i have is at its simplest. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Comment: I am wondering why do i get -1 for a question i asked? I am new in coding and that was a question, not an answer... very strange..

Comment: I couldn't tell you, I wasn't either down-voter (you have 2 down, 1 up.) Perhaps because it could be perceieved as off-topic as it may have been more appropriate over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use variable name in isset(), it will return false if the variable is null like

```
if($meta['test1'] or $meta['test2'] or $meta['testn']){
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

It's common in every language.

Comment: This is not proper. It will generate notice when compiler compiles it. Use of `isset` function is proper.

Comment: I use it recently and I never got notice... It's like an isset. He is not referring to a variable, he is referring to an index of an array. If the index of the array is null or does not exist, it will just jump it over.

Comment: Yes, i got notice using "or" as well

Comment: If this isn't generating notices, you are most likely surpressing notices somewhere in your php.ini or error_reporting()

Answer (score 0):

@Anil Your question is not well detailed. So I am assuming that `$meta` is what you need.

What you have done so far is okay just the problem that you did not follow PHP coding standards.

Use something like below:

```
if(   isset ($meta['test1']) 
   || isset ($meta['test2']) 
   || isset ($meta['test3']) 
   || isset ($meta['test4']) 
   || isset ($meta['test5'])
) { 
    // do this 
}
```

To know more about coding standars, please visit [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php).

Comment: Sorry about not being clear, $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property', true );